# Scala can't cast types Publisher[Publisher[_ <: T]] cannot be applied to (Flux[Flux[String]]

Tags: scala, project-reactor

I implemented simple streams in Scala with Project Reactor stream implementation.

```
  val iterators: Iterable[Flux[String]] = for (i <- 0 to 4000) yield Flux.interval(5 seconds).map(_.toString)
  val publishers: Flux[Flux[String]] = Flux.just(iterators).flatMapIterable(identity)
  Flux.merge(publishers, 1)
```

Tried to compile that code but got error

```
Error:(156, 8) overloaded method value merge with alternatives:
  [I](prefetch: Int, sources: org.reactivestreams.Publisher[_ <: I]*)reactor.core.scala.publisher.Flux[I] <and>
  [I](sources: org.reactivestreams.Publisher[_ <: I]*)reactor.core.scala.publisher.Flux[I] <and>
  [T](source: org.reactivestreams.Publisher[org.reactivestreams.Publisher[_ <: T]], concurrency: Int)reactor.core.scala.publisher.Flux[T]
 cannot be applied to (reactor.core.scala.publisher.Flux[reactor.core.scala.publisher.Flux[String]], Int)
```

Why scala can't cast these types ?

`Flux.merge(publishers)` works well but when I pass integer argument, scala compiler fails with error.

Comment: I think you need to provide the versions of libraries that you are using in your project. Ex(scala, reactor-core etc)

Comment: Are you using reactor-scala-extensions? Or directly using reactor-core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using reactor-scala-extensions, it a bug that will be fixed in 0.4.8